# how can I prevent a redirect to localhost - ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, localhost, ip-address, webmin

I am in the process of setting up a Ubuntu Server (17.04) with Webmin and Wordpress. The ip address to the server is 192.168.0.2. Browsing to the address `http://192.168.0.2/` will evoke a redirect to `http://localhost/`. This works if calling up the website locally; but not if connecting from a different computer on the local network.

If calling `http://192.168.0.2/my.html` there is not redirect. It works as expected. But without a page it redirects. Is looks like it is an Apache setting that is not in place.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a bit more description, browsing with which browser - does the address literally change to say "localhost"? If you ping the server address what happens? If you ping 192.168.0.2 from a different comp you get to localhost (127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0)?

Comment: I just added some more info - ping works as expected. It is not browser related - redirect is happening with FF and Chromium (and others.)

Comment: Maybe post your apache2.conf and any logs from /var/log/httpd that appear when you access the web root.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that I had entered in Wordpress `http://localhost` as URL instead of the ip address `http://192.168.0.2`. This caused the page to redirect to `http://localhost`. This is a bit of a buggy way of handling the situation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you only routing on the internal network, or are you opening to internet eventually; you'll want to look at vhosts.

Comment: I would eventually like to open to the Internet. I got it somewhat working using my TP-ER6020 Router by adding a Virtual Server under NAT, but do not get to use https. I am missing a tunneling setup ... I still need to figure out how to get it working. I would like to use DMZ, but get the error _The DMZ subnet is in conflict with other port's. Please enter another one._